# Distance between selected points in order

Tags: arcgis-pro, point, distance

I am using ArcGIS Pro and need to find the distance between selected points by time & day. I have a large file that contains information about the time, date and location of points. I would like to be able to find the distance travelled per day using this data, but the points need to be ordered by time (it can't use nearest neighbors, because there is some circling back during the day). The file contains many days so I'd like to find a tool that would separate by day and use time as the ordinal component.

Comment: The core software would support this kind of query, of course, but it seems a stretch that some existing tool would do exactly this. What have you tried?

Comment: To create the line, you could use this standard tool: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/points-to-line.htm

To get information out, have you looked at linear referencing tools? Maybe start here if you don't know what to try first: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/linear-referencing/introduction-to-linear-referencing.htm